# Taking the value of a multiple select element and adding each in an array of object

Tags: javascript, html, json, dynamic

Good day, seniors!

Ignore the choice of ids, names, names of variables. I was just testing this code first before putting it in the project I'm working on. Thank you in advance!

I can't seem to get the selected value of the select element and add it in an array of object

here's the code:

```js
let list = [];
let selectedVal;

function changes(event) {
  selectedVal = event.target.value;
  list.push({
    selectedVal
  })
}

const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll("select");

selectEls.forEach((select) => {
  select.addEventListener('change', changes);
});


const addDets = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let officials = {
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    age: document.getElementById("age").value,
    favColor: selectedVal,
    location: selectedVal
  }
  list.push(officials)
  document.forms[0].reset();
  console.log(list);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addDets);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" id="form">

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age">

    <select name="favorites" id="fav">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Favorite Colors</option>
      <option value="Red">R</option>
      <option value="Blue">B</option>
      <option value="Yellow">Y</option>
    </select>

    <select name="location" id="loc">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Location</option>
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="V">V</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btn" type="submit">OK</button>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are currently adding everything as an object to an array. What's the output you're looking for? Do you want to add it to an array when OK is pressed or when it's selected from the dropdown?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding! I see, I'm getting confused because this is my first time encountering this. 

I would like it to be added in the array when OK is pressed like after answering all the fields

Answer (score 0):

What's going wrong:

You are using `selectedVal` to retrieve the values of `select` elements. The issue here is that you are trying to store multiple values into a single variable. Thus, when you select `red` for example, `selectedValue` will contain red and update both `favColor` and `location` with that value.

Instead, you can simply retrieve their value the same way you retrieved the value of name and age.

```
document.getElementById("fav").value;
document.getElementById("loc").value
```

keep in mind that this will return the **value** rather than the option, so if you pick the color `R` it will store the value `Red`.

Working snippet:

```js
let list = [];

const addDets = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let officials = {
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    age: document.getElementById("age").value,
    favColor: document.getElementById("fav").value,
    location: document.getElementById("loc").value
  }
  list.push(officials)
  document.forms[0].reset();
  console.log(list);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addDets);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" id="form">

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age">

    <select name="favorites" id="fav">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Favorite Colors</option>
      <option value="Red">R</option>
      <option value="Blue">B</option>
      <option value="Yellow">Y</option>
    </select>

    <select name="location" id="loc">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Location</option>
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="V">V</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btn" type="submit">OK</button>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, it was pretty simple. I was just making it complicated. Tried this and it works. I got my array of objects with a different values depending on what is selected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Skip all the ids of the input elements and just use the name attribute. On the submit event the form is `ev.target` and then you can get all the values by `ev.target.[name].value`.

```js
let list = [];

const addDets = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let officials = {
    name: ev.target.name.value,
    age: ev.target.age.value,
    favColor: ev.target.favorites.value,
    location: ev.target.location.value
  }
  list.push(officials);
  ev.target.reset();
  console.log(list);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.forms.form.addEventListener('submit', addDets);
});
```

```html
<form action="" name="form">

  <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>

  <label>Age: <input type="number" name="age"></label>

  <select name="favorites">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Favorite Colors</option>
    <option value="Red">R</option>
    <option value="Blue">B</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Y</option>
  </select>

  <select name="location">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Location</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
  </select>
  
  <button>OK</button>
</form>
```

An alternative could be to use [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) for getting all values and then run through the entities.

```js
let list = [];

const addDets = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let formData = new FormData(ev.target);
  let officials = {};
  [...formData.entries()].forEach(ent => officials[ent[0]] = ent[1]);
  list.push(officials);
  ev.target.reset();
  console.log(list);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.forms.form.addEventListener('submit', addDets);
});
```

```html
<form action="" name="form">

  <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>

  <label>Age: <input type="number" name="age"></label>

  <select name="favorites">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Favorite Colors</option>
    <option value="Red">R</option>
    <option value="Blue">B</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Y</option>
  </select>

  <select name="location">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Location</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
  </select>
  
  <button>OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding! I'm new to handling datas in Java Script. This is my first time encountering FormData(). I'll keep this for future use. Thank you very much!